# how to configure Content-Security-Policy dotnet

Tags: asp.net, owasp

I would like to seek help. Im currently configuring the Content-Security-Policy for an existing web app for some owasp works. However, im unable to find there the csp is being created or configured.

This is the generated report from owasp

```
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:; report-uri https://121.23.142.1/onb21_owasp/IdentityServer/csp/report
```

[image]

Im also using postman for some tests and found out that there are some customheaders

[image]

As you can see on the image there are 3 custom headers but on the middle one, is the one i can configure or change it's value. but what i need to change are the top and bottom value. i could not find any lead pointing to CSP.

Could it be that the top and bottom custom headers are dynamically generated?

Answer (score 0):

you can add dynamically meta tags from code behind